# Error term from for loop with (anova) in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I searched various answers about similar problem in for loop with aov () function. However, I could not find a solution and I am still having the following error

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = i ~ epa2, data = df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'epa2')
```

It worked perfectly when on its own. However, after adding the for loop, it no longer works. Why does the code below produces the error above?

```
cat=c("MAP","MAT","ndvi")
for(i in cat) {
model <-aov(i~epa2, data=df)
LSD_A = LSD.test(model,
                 trt = "epa2",
                 DFerror = model$df.residual,
                 MSerror = deviance(model)/model$df.residual,
                 alpha = 0.05,
                 p.adj = "bonferroni",
                 group = TRUE,
                 console = TRUE)
ascend_A = LSD_A$groups %>%
  group_by(rownames(LSD_A$groups))
ascend_A$epa2 <- factor(ascend_A$`rownames(LSD_A$groups)`,
                        levels = c("Golomoti","Linthipe","Kandeu","Nsipe","Nyambi","Nsanama","Mtubwi"))
ascend_A=ascend_A%>%arrange(epa2)
MeanSE_A = df %>%
  group_by(epa2) %>%
  summarise(avg_A = mean(i),
            se = sd(i)/sqrt(length(i)))
p1<-ggplot(MeanSE_A, aes(x = epa2,y = avg_A))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           color = "black",
           fill="darkred",
           position = position_dodge(width=0.9),
           width = 0.8)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = avg_A + se,
                    ymin = avg_A - se), 
                position = position_dodge(width=0.9), 
                width = 0.25)+
  labs(x="EPA",y= i ,title= paste(i,"by EPAs"))+
  geom_text(aes(x = epa2,
                y = avg_A + se,
                label = paste(round(ascend_A$i,1),
                              ascend_A$groups
                )),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),
            vjust = -(0.5))+
  theme_classic()
  print(p1)}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do.  But `cat` is a character vector.  So `for(i in cat)` followed by `model <-aov(i~epa2, data=df)` and `summarise(avg_A = mean(i)` is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to dynamically pass a value into `formula` type, consider `paste` + `as.formula` or `reformulate`:

```r
cat=c("MAP","MAT","ndvi") 

for(i in cat) { 
  fml <- as.formula(paste(i, "~epa2"))
  model <-aov(fml, data=df)
  ...
}
```

```r
cat=c("MAP","MAT","ndvi") 

for(i in cat) { 
  fml <- reformulate("epa2", i)
  model <-aov(fml, data=df)
  ...
}
```

Similarly, you can do the same with `aggregate` to replace `summarise` call. Subsequent `do.call` and `setNames` needed for cleanup due to calling multiple aggregate functions:

```r
agg_raw <- aggregate(reformulate("epa2", i), df, 
                      function(x) c(avg_A=mean(x),
                                    se=sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))
                     )

MeanSE_A <- do.call(data.frame, agg_raw)

MeanSE_A <- setNames(MeanSE_A, gsub(paste0(i, "."), "", colnames(MeanSE_A)))
...
```

Comment: still working on debugging this. Is df$i does not work? I tried paste("df$",i), which also did not work. How do you specify the different i in th df$i?

Comment: To dynamically pass name use brackets: `df[[i]]`.